# Single quotation marks: punctuation marks outside or inside?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I use single quotation marks to provide translations of foreign terms and to highlight titles of parts of my dissertation.

I'm confused where I should put commas and periods when they appear next to the inverted comma, meaning inside or outside?

Thank you

Comment: I would put them inside, but then again I would use italics for this purpose, not quotation marks.

Comment: There are ten related questions in the sidebar. Do none of those answer this question?

Comment: I found only questions about double quotation marks.